# Complex branching and merging in history TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, branching-and-merging, source-control-explorer

It is possible to create a branch from a historic changeset. The situation that I have now is that I have created a branch of a repository from a (for example) 3 months ago. After that I have created the branch, I want to  and I want to merge only specific changesets from 1 month ago, and want to keep the rest of the branch the same.

When I try to tell visual studio (source control explorer) that I want to merge specific changesets to that new branch, the changeset of the previous months are not shown. Is there any other way than manual work to merge the changes of the specific changeset on the historic branch that I have created?

Answer (score 0):

Using Source Control Explorer (View->Other windows-> source control explorer) right click on your repository, select "Branching and merging", then "Merge", once the Source Control Merge Wizard windows show you should see two options: "All changes up to a specific version" and "Selected Changeset", select "selected changeset" and choose your source and target branches. This window will give you a list that contains specific changesets that have been checked in to the source branch but not merge into the target branch, keep in mind that you can select contiguous set of changes to move in this merge operation, I hope this helps

Comment: I used the selected changes option, but the changes do not show up, probably because it is an branch created based on a changeset in the past.

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible to create a branch from a historic changeset?**

When a branch is created you could choose the historical point in time when it takes effect (date, changeset, etc).

[image: Branch dialog]

For more detail steps please refer this tutorial in MSDN: [**Branch a branch**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-folders-files#branch-a-branch)

---

> When I try to tell visual studio (source control explorer) that I want
>   to merge specific changesets to that new branch, the changeset of the
>   previous months are not shown.

Not sure why the changeset are not shown, make sure you have select the right option when you do the merge. Another way is directly using [tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command) to do the merge. For example:

```
tf merge /version:C137~C1xx  oldbranch newbranch /recursive
```

***Note:*** you could only merge a single changeset or continuous changesets

Comment: I know how you can merge specific changesets, but the problem is when you created a branch based on a changeset in the past, and you try to merge only specific changeset after that specific date in the past, it does not show as mergeable changes.

Comment: @Ricconnect Sorry ,could you explain more clearly about  `I want to keep the rest of the branch the same.` I' m not totally got your point for this, which branch you want to keep. Could you use branch A , branch B to stand for "the branch", "that branch" , "new branch". It's easy to miss up what you are talking about. In my opinion, seems you have three branches, but I can't not figure out which branch you want to merge, which is l source ,which is the target.